# Laravel Eloquent, Return a JSON result using Polymorphic Relations?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I created a Polymorphic Relation and I want to return a Json containing the object with it relations.

- Look my table 'feed'

[image: Table Feed]
[image: Data]

In models/Feed.php

```
class Feed extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'feed';

    public function objeto()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

In FeedController.php

```
class FeedController extends BaseController {
    public function teste(){
        return Feed::with('objeto')->get();
    }
}
```

So, I got this error

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>
> Class name must be a valid object or a string

If i put this

```
class FeedController extends BaseController {
    public function teste(){
        return Feed::get();
    }
}
```

works, but whitout relations.

If i put this

```
class FeedController extends BaseController {
    public function teste(){
        return Feed::find(1)->objeto()->get();
    }
}
```

works, but retrieve only the object related

So, I need the result with the object and relations.

Comment: Show your models with polymorphic relations defined

Comment: Have you tried 'Objeto' instead of 'objeto'? Do the class has a namespace? If so, you must include it